# Executing a command out of conda env

Tags: python, shell, anaconda

Im activating a conda environment beginning of the script execution but in which I want to execute a command using os.system() out of conda environment with in a loop.

Example:-

```
conde continues ...

for n in range(5):
    # Some code here with in conda environment
    # Only the following command should be executed out of current conda environment
    os.system('some command ...')
    # Some code here with in same conda environment

conde continues ...
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Commands run with `os.system` will inherit the environment variables, and hence run in the activated Conda env:

```bash
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ python -c "import os; os.system('which python')"
/usr/bin/python

$ conda activate

(base) $ which python
/Users/user/miniconda3/bin/python

(base) $ python -c "import os; os.system('which python')"
/Users/user/miniconda3/bin/python
```

and there aren't any options to manipulate the environment variables without actually manipulating the current environment, which you likely don't want to do.

Instead, you want [the `subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run), which provides more control over how the subprocess is run.  As a simple example, let's strip the `$PATH` of any entries with `"conda"` in them and rerun with this reduced `$PATH`

```python
import os
import subprocess

path_cur = os.environ['PATH']

# remove '*conda*' entries
path_new = ':'.join(p for p in path_cur.split(':') if 'conda' not in p)

subprocess.run(['which', 'python'], env={'PATH': path_cur})
# /Users/user/miniconda3/bin/python
# CompletedProcess(args=['which', 'python'], returncode=0)

subprocess.run(['which', 'python'], env={'PATH': path_new})
# /usr/bin/python
# CompletedProcess(args=['which', 'python'], returncode=0)
```