# How can I install two versions of Python on a single Conda Environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, python-venv, miniconda

I need to have a conda environment with **two versions of python** (3.5.3 and 3.7.1).

Is it possible to have multiple python versions installed in a single conda environment?
And if yes, how can I do so?

Comment: I'd be surprised if this doesn't have a clear duplicate to suggest, but I couldn't find one after briefly searching. If anyone does find one, please ping me and I'll join a CV.

Comment: Thank you Grismar and merv, that's exactly what i was thinking two , I was just confused if I was missing something. Well I will try to use two venvs each with a single python version and i will see if that solves my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Create multiple environments

Please take time to read [the Conda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/index.html), which covers [using different Python versions](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-python).

One cannot install different Python versions in the same environment. As @Grismar commented, it is a central purpose of environments to isolate different Python installations from each other. Instead, create a separate environment for each Python version (or, better, for each project):

```bash
# v3.5.3 environment (name is arbitrary)
conda create -n python3_5_3 python=3.5.3  # also include additional packages here

# v3.7.1 env
conda create -n python3_7_1 python=3.7.1
```

Then activate to use the environment of choice:

```bash
conda activate python3_7_1
python
```

---

### Running multiple Python processes

@Egret commented that OP may need to run code in two different versions in a single context. However, asking to co-install those two versions in one environment would make this [an XY problem](https://xyproblem.info) - rather than asking how to solve a problem, one has instead asked how to implement a (possibly inappropriate) solution to that problem.

If this is the case, then please see these related answers on how to execute within multiple environments via subprocesses:

- [Running script in Conda environment from within script in another Conda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72663449/570918)
- [Switching environments within a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72397125/570918)
- [Executing a command out of conda env](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57872850/570918)

That is, I'd regard the idiomatic solution as using multiple environments and orchestrating execution within them as appropriate. The hard part left out in those answers is exchanging non-trivial data types across processes (e.g., via serialization), but I think that is outside the scope of this thread.

---

### Testing co-installation with Conda and Mamba

Simply trying to install both with Conda doesn't give a clear error, in my opinion:

```bash
$ conda create -n snakes python=3.5.3 python=3.7.1
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python[version='3.5.3.*,3.7.1.*']
```

However, [Mamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba#readme) seems to give more sensible feedback (and much faster):

```bash
$ mamba create -n snakes python=3.5.3 python=3.7.1

                  __    __    __    __
                 /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \
                /    \/    \/    \/    \
███████████████/  /██/  /██/  /██/  /████████████████████████
              /  / \   / \   / \   / \  \____
             /  /   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \__,
            / _/                       \_____/  `
            |/
        ███╗   ███╗ █████╗ ███╗   ███╗██████╗  █████╗
        ████╗ ████║██╔══██╗████╗ ████║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗
        ██╔████╔██║███████║██╔████╔██║██████╔╝███████║
        ██║╚██╔╝██║██╔══██║██║╚██╔╝██║██╔══██╗██╔══██║
        ██║ ╚═╝ ██║██║  ██║██║ ╚═╝ ██║██████╔╝██║  ██║
        ╚═╝     ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝     ╚═╝╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝

        mamba (0.11.1) supported by @QuantStack

        GitHub:  https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba
        Twitter: https://twitter.com/QuantStack

█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████


Looking for: ['python=3.5.3', 'python=3.7.1']

conda-forge/osx-64       Using cache
conda-forge/noarch       Using cache
pkgs/main/osx-64         Using cache
pkgs/main/noarch         Using cache
pkgs/r/osx-64            Using cache
pkgs/r/noarch            Using cache

Encountered problems while solving:
  - cannot install both python-3.7.1-h145921a_1000 and python-3.5.3-0
```

Comment: The reason of OP, as I guess, is that two packages in their app depend on different versions of Python. That's why they need to install multiple versions of Python in the same environment

Comment: @Egret I realize your comment is rather old, but I just noticed it has several upvotes, so I feel obliged to address it. I've updated the answer with some references about orchestrating execution in across multiple Python environments. Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

I have two different versions in same environment
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMU8k.png

I have two versions of python in one environment.
when i enter python it gives me python version 3.8.0
and when i enter python3 it gives me python version 3.9.1