# Running script in Conda environment from within script in another Conda environment

Tags: python, subprocess, conda, virtual-environment

I have two scripts, let's call them `master.py` and `subject.py`. `master.py` is supposed to run in Python3, while `subject.py`, in Python2, therefore I created two separate Conda environments for them which we'll call `env-master` and `env-subject`. However, `master.py` is supposed to run `subject.py` as a subprocess. Something like:

```
subprocess.run('conda run -n env-subject python2 /path/to/subject.py')
```

Is it actually possible to make such a thing work? Because, as far as I understand, only one conda environment can be active at any one time. I wonder if there are workarounds for basically using `master.py` to run multiple batches of `subject.py` while it simultaneously analyzes the output files of any executions which already completed, and never running more than N `subject.py`s at once.

Comment: Have you tried it? One can certainly have multiple environments activated *in separate processes*, which is what you describe.

Comment: @merv yes, I get errors like `ImportError: No module named matplotlib_inline.backend_inline` (from within the sub-script), or `the procedure entry point PyWinBufferView could not be located in the dynamic link library [...]` (as a pop-up window)

Comment: @merv worth bearing in mind that I'm using Jupyter, but when I run it from the terminal with an env already loading in what happens is it uses the python of the base environment. More specifically, since the sub-script is supposed to run in Python2 then errors happen because conda is using Python3... It's [an issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9587) on GitHub

Comment: What terminal? `tmux`, VSCode and GitBash have known issues with activation.

Comment: @merv Powershell and cmd.exe (I'm on Windows unfortunately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me. Here's an example:

### Scripts

**so-py23-mix.py**

```python
import sys
import subprocess

print("This is the main process")
print(sys.version)

subprocess.run(['conda', 'run', '-n', 'so-py2', 'python', 'so-py2-sub.py'])
```

**so-py2-sub.py**

```python
import sys

print "This is the subprocess"
print sys.version
```

### Running

**shell commands**

```bash
mamba create -yn so-py2 python=2
mamba create -yn so-py3 python=3

mamba activate so-py3

python so-py23-mix.py
```

**output**

```bash
This is the main process
3.10.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Jun 14 2022, 07:09:13) [Clang 13.0.1 ]
This is the subprocess
2.7.15 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar  5 2020, 14:58:04)
[GCC Clang 9.0.1 ]
```

### Running 2

Also can get exactly the same behavior without activating, but instead launching through `conda run`:

**shell**

```bash
mamba create -yn so-py2 python=2
mamba create -yn so-py3 python=3

conda run -n so-py3 --live-stream python so-py23-mix.py
```

**results**

```bash
This is the main process
3.10.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Jun 14 2022, 07:09:13) [Clang 13.0.1 ]
This is the subprocess
2.7.15 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar  5 2020, 14:58:04)
[GCC Clang 9.0.1 ]
```

Note that my **base** environment is Python v3.8.

Comment: Thank you, indeed it is possible. It appears that I was having problems with Jupyter, and judging from internet results it causes some issues on these matters.

Comment: I've tried this in visual studio and it doesn't work: ERROR conda.cli.main_run:execute(33): Subprocess for 'conda run ['python', 'foo.py']' command failed.

Comment: @Vidar it looks as though you didn't not specify an environment (here `-n` and `so-py2`) in the call. This is obligatory.

Comment: @merv thanks very much - I was clearly missing that as it now works.