# How to run a function by passing the arguments and retrieve the results

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a script `myScript.py` with a function `myFunc(a, b)`. How can I use `subprocess` module to run this function on a given conda environment with a given arguments? The solution which I would like to obtain is:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(["path\to\python", nameOfFunction, arguments a and b])
```

where result is a result of a function `myFunc(a,b)`.

Comment: Why don't you just import and call it?

Comment: I want to use another conda environment to run this function and retrieve the result

Comment: You can't invoke a function directly from outside the script. A library like `click` will make it easier to write a script that *exposes* an interface for calling a given function.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply do this

```py
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(["path\to\python", "-c","import pyfile;myFunc(5, 10)"])
```

but if your file is in another directory
you can use two ways

this going to append directory path to python sys paths

```py
import sys;sys.path.append("path\to\pyfile/directory")
```

then import it

or

```py
import os;os.chdir("path\to\pyfile/directory")
```

learn more about [os.chdir](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-chdir-method/) and [sys.path](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sys-path-in-python/)

if you don't know why did i put the -c in subprocess.run, here something that will be helpful [python cmdline](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html)

Comment: so I can run for example `subprocess.run(["path\to\python",  "-c", "import numpy as np; np.sqrt(2)"])` but how can I retrieve the result? If my function returns for example `DataFarme` - is it possible to return also dataframe or always a string?

Comment: @Jason it's always a string. the only way is to turn it to JSON data and then load it by using `json.loads`

Comment: but how can I pass arguments of different types? Let's say that in my standard python environment I have DataFrame `df` and my function as an arguments takes this dataframe. I cannot write `subprocess.run(["path\to\python", "-c", f"import pyfile;myFunc({df})"])`

Comment: Using binary directly can be unreliable for virtual environments. Conda users should prefer `conda run` as [demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72665608/570918).