# Switching environments within a python script

Tags: python, matlab, conda

I have a python script which needs to call the matlab engine so that I can use a code base (many funcitons) without having to rewrite a ton of code into python.  Problem is the solution I found for running matlab requires an environemnt set up.  I already have an environment set up to run my scripts in and I need to be able to switch between them.  Can I do this with os?   I am running this on a windows machine in a linux vm in a locally hosted jupyter session.

Example jmatlab
https://am111.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jmatlab_install.html

**Pseudocode to give you an idea of what I want to do...**

```
os.environ["jmatlab"]
#matlab engine stuff...
os.environ["orignal_env"]
```

Comment: You're saying you want to switch your Jupyter notebook to accept MATLAB commands? Or do you just want to run a MATLAB script from within Python? For the latter case, see here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html

Comment: This will run inside a jupyter cell right?  So long as its a locally run one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that I've answered something similar to this before, but can't find an exact fit. One can't switch a Python process mid-execution to have context-sensitive evaluation, like OP describes. However, `os.system` or `subprocess.run` could be used run the other Python code (as a separate script) inside another environment. Without a detailed mock example, we can't detail the sharing of data across the processes. But it would broadly be using `conda run -n jmatlab python matlab_engine_stuff.py` to run in the other environment.

Try looking into `conda run` (e.g., `conda run --help`). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57873881/570918) is also loosely related, though it is about running system commands outside the Python's environment. There might be some applicable solutions for running subparts of code under separate Python 2 and 3 processes.